# how to set local notification for every two weeks

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, localnotification

How to trigger local notification for every two weeks?

**What i did was:**

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = UILocalNotification.new;
localNotification.repeatInterval = 14;
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:10 sinceDate:notificationDate];
localNotification.alertBody = notificationMessage;
localNotification.alertAction = @"Open";
localNotification.category = @"default_category";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Comment: Please try the solution and give your response its working or not?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
notification.userInfo = @{@"notification_identifier":@"After14Days"};
notification.fireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:(60*60*24*14)];
notification.alertBody = @"Text to display";
notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

Comment: i dont think this will work. it will just delay notification with one day

Comment: @KDeogharkar I did `dateByAddingTimeInterval:(60*60*24*14)` so it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Set repeatInterval of UILocalNotification to NSCalendarUnitDay.